# Google Cloud Data Transfer to a GCS subfolder

Tags: amazon-s3, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-dataflow

I am trying to transfer data from AWS S3 bucket (e.g. s3://mySrcBkt) to GCS location ( a folder under a bucket as gs://myDestBkt/myDestination ). I could not find the same option from Interface as it has only provision to provide bucket and not a subfolder. Neither I found the similar povision from the storagetransfer API. Here is my code snippet:

```
    String SOURCE_BUCKET = .... ;
    String ACCESS_KEY  = .....;
    String SECRET_ACCESS_KEY  = .....;
    String DESTINATION_BUCKET   = .......;
    String STATUS   =   "ENABLED";

    TransferJob transferJob =
            new TransferJob()
                .setName(NAME)
                .setDescription(DESCRIPTION)
                .setProjectId(PROJECT)


                .setTransferSpec(
                    new TransferSpec()

                        .setObjectConditions(new ObjectConditions()
                                .setIncludePrefixes(includePrefixes))
                        .setTransferOptions(new TransferOptions()
                                .setDeleteObjectsFromSourceAfterTransfer(false)
                                .setOverwriteObjectsAlreadyExistingInSink(false)
                                .setDeleteObjectsUniqueInSink(false))

                        .setAwsS3DataSource(
                            new AwsS3Data()
                                .setBucketName(SOURCE_BUCKET)
                                .setAwsAccessKey(
                                    new AwsAccessKey()
                                        .setAccessKeyId(ACCESS_KEY)
                                        .setSecretAccessKey(SECRET_ACCESS_KEY))

                                )
                .setGcsDataSink(
                            new GcsData()
                                .setBucketName(DESTINATION_BUCKET)
                        ))


                .setSchedule(
                    new Schedule()
                        .setScheduleStartDate(date)
                        .setScheduleEndDate(date)
                        .setStartTimeOfDay(time))
                .setStatus(STATUS);
```

Unfortunately I could not find anywhere to mention the destination folder for this transfer. I know gsutil rsync has similar however the scale & data integrity is a concern. Can anyone guide me/point me any way/workaround to achieve the goal ?

Answer (score 0):

As the bucket and not a subdirectory is the available option for data transfer destination, the workaround for this scenario would be doing the transfer to your bucket, then doing the rsync operation between your bucket and the subdirectory, just keep in mind that you should try running the `gsutil -m rsync -r -d -n` to verify what it'll do, as [you could delete data accidentally](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/rsync#be-careful-when-using--d-option).